# vba code for copying body of a stationery mail into a new mail in lotus notes

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I am trying to create a macro which will open a new lotus notes mail, attaches certain files to it and copy and paste the body from a stationery mail.

I am stuck in the last part where I have to copy the BODY of the stationery mail and paste it in the new mail which I have created.

Below is the code which I have tried, but only the files are getting attached but unable to copy the body from the stationery

Any Help is appreciated........

```
isattached = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Start Lotus Notes Session
Set nSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
On Error GoTo err_send
Set nMailDb = nSession.GetDatabase("", "mailin/GBG180.nsf")

' Open the Stationery View
Set nView = nMailDb.GetView("Stationery")
Set nWorkspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set nCursor = nView.GetFirstDocument

Do While Not nCursor Is Nothing
    ' get stationery value
    StationeryName = nCursor.GetItemValue("MailStationeryName")(0)
    ' match form template selection versus stationery
    If StationeryName = St_name Then

        Set nMailDoc = nMailDb.CreateDocument("Memo")
        Set AttachME = nMailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("ATTACHMENT")
        'Open the PDF folder and attach the files
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(PdfPath)
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            Set EmbedObj = AttachME.EmbedObject(1454, "", PdfPath & objFile.Name)
            isattached = True
            Application.Wait (15)
        Next
        subjectname = policy_num & "-" & aname & "-FoS Invoice & Wording" & " " & Format(DateValue(Now()), "YYYY") & "- Confidential"

        If (isattached) Then
            'Set nMailDoc = nWorkspace.EDITDOCUMENT(True, nCursor)
            nMailDoc.Subject = subjectname
        Else
            Set nMailDoc = Nothing
            Set AttachME = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
        nMailDoc.Save True, True, False
        Set nMailDoc = Nothing
        Set nCursor = Nothing

        GoTo nMail_OK
    Else
        Set nCursor = nView.GetNextDocument(nCursor)
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Domino there are Default item names to store data in. The Body (inlcuding all attachments) in a mail is always called "Body", and not "ATTACHMENTS" as in your example.

You need to replace these lines

```
Set AttachME = nMailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("ATTACHMENT")
'Open the PDF folder and attach the files
...
```

with these

```
Dim bodyStationary as NotesRichtextItem
'- get the richtext from the stationary
Set bodyStationary = nCursor.GetFirstItem( "Body" )

'- create richtextitem in new document
Set AttachME = nMailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")

'- append the stationary
Call AttachMe.AppendRTItem( bodyStationary )

'- add the attachments
'Open the PDF folder and attach the files
...
```

If you want to have the attachments above the text of the stationary, just move the AppendRTItem below the Foreach- loop.

Don't forget to add `Attachme.AddNewline( 2 )` in that case, as otherwise the text will directly follow the attachments.

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Torsten Link. The Code is working absolutely fine.....